# Dynamically pass dictionary name python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, import

I have 2 scripts, say `test.py` and `main.py`.
My `test.py` contains only dictionaries (No other code).

I am running `main.py` by passing dict_name as a argument. Here I want to fetch the dict passed as argument from `test.py` and display it's content in `main.py`.

`test.py`

```
config_123={"name":"Dave","age":25}
config_89033 = {"name":"alex","age":30}
.....
```

To run `main.py` (Note: here I am passing 1st argument with dots)

```
python main.py 1.2.3
```

`main.py`

```
import sys
from test import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
   if len(sys.argv) != 2:
       print "error message"
       sys.exit(1)
   else:
       dict_name=sys.argv[1]
       #if dict_name contains '.' , replace it
       if '.' in dict_name:
           temp_name=dict_name.replace(".","")   #gives me 123
       else:
           temp_name = dict_name

       #here i want to print the content of dict from test.py
       print config_123    #it prints dict (as i am importing * from test)
       #but i need to create it dynamically.
       print "config_"+temp_name    #obviously it prints it as a string "config_123"  
       #how should i call it here?
```

In this case, how can I call `config_123` from `test.py` and display the dict?

Comment: maybe create `config["1.2.3"]` instead of `config_123`

Comment: Why can't you just do `python main.py 123`? I don't understand why the dots are needed / checked for.

Comment: @furas There are 100's of dict already created..so i can't change it. Also the only way to  pass argument is with "dots".

Comment: @cricket_007- because sometimes i need to pass some extra info as argument and from that i have to fetch `only numbers with dots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the module with `import test` and use  `getattr()` on the module:

```
import test

print getattr(test, 'config_123')
```

Output:

```
{'age': 25, 'name': 'Dave'}
```

Or in your case:

```
print getattr(test, 'config_' + temp_name )
```

Comment: Ya, this approach will work with slight change. `some_var="config_"+temp_name` gives me `config_123` and then `print getattr(test, some_var)` is working

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work.

You can use the built-in locals() function to get any local variables as a dictionary.  Then, the get function for a dict seems to get the correct config:

```
import sys, test

dname = sys.argv[1]
config1 = {'name':'Bob'}
config2 = {'name':'Alice'}

#if the variable is local
print locals().get(dname, None)
#if it's in the test module
#config = getattr(test, dname)
```

The output looks like this:

```
python main.py config2
{'name': 'Alice'}

python main.py config1
{'name': 'Bob'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also store the configs as a single dictionary keyed off of their name and then get them from there.

```
test.py
=======

configs = {'config_123': {"name":"Dave","age":25},
           'config_89033': {"name":"alex","age":30}}


main.py
=======
from test import configs

config = configs.get('config_123')
```